# Dissassembling virtual methods in multiple inheritance. How is the vtable working?

Tags: c++, assembly, vtable

Assuming the following C++ source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class BaseTest {
  public:
  int a;

  BaseTest(): a(2){}

  virtual int gB() {
    return a;
  };
};

class SubTest: public BaseTest {
  public:
  int b;

  SubTest(): b(4){}
};

class TriTest: public BaseTest {
  public:
  int c;
  TriTest(): c(42){}
};

class EvilTest: public SubTest, public TriTest {
  public:
  virtual int gB(){
    return b;
  }
};

int main(){
  EvilTest * t2 = new EvilTest;

  TriTest * t3 = t2;

  printf("%d\n",t3->gB());
  printf("%d\n",t2->gB());
  return 0;
}
```

`-fdump-class-hierarchy` gives me:

```
[...]
Vtable for EvilTest
EvilTest::_ZTV8EvilTest: 6u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI8EvilTest)
16    (int (*)(...))EvilTest::gB
24    (int (*)(...))-16
32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI8EvilTest)
40    (int (*)(...))EvilTest::_ZThn16_N8EvilTest2gBEv

Class EvilTest
   size=32 align=8
   base size=32 base align=8
EvilTest (0x0x7f1ba98a8150) 0
    vptr=((& EvilTest::_ZTV8EvilTest) + 16u)
  SubTest (0x0x7f1ba96df478) 0
      primary-for EvilTest (0x0x7f1ba98a8150)
    BaseTest (0x0x7f1ba982ba80) 0
        primary-for SubTest (0x0x7f1ba96df478)
  TriTest (0x0x7f1ba96df4e0) 16
      vptr=((& EvilTest::_ZTV8EvilTest) + 40u)
    BaseTest (0x0x7f1ba982bae0) 16
        primary-for TriTest (0x0x7f1ba96df4e0)
```

Disassembly shows:

```
34  int main(){
   0x000000000040076d <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000000000040076e <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000400771 <+4>: push   rbx
   0x0000000000400772 <+5>: sub    rsp,0x18

35    EvilTest * t2 = new EvilTest;
   0x0000000000400776 <+9>: mov    edi,0x20
   0x000000000040077b <+14>:    call   0x400670 <_Znwm@plt>
   0x0000000000400780 <+19>:    mov    rbx,rax
   0x0000000000400783 <+22>:    mov    rdi,rbx
   0x0000000000400786 <+25>:    call   0x4008a8 <EvilTest::EvilTest()>
   0x000000000040078b <+30>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rbx

36    
37    TriTest * t3 = t2;
   0x000000000040078f <+34>:    cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x0
   0x0000000000400794 <+39>:    je     0x4007a0 <main()+51>
   0x0000000000400796 <+41>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x000000000040079a <+45>:    add    rax,0x10
   0x000000000040079e <+49>:    jmp    0x4007a5 <main()+56>
   0x00000000004007a0 <+51>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004007a5 <+56>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rax

38    
39    printf("%d\n",t3->gB());
   0x00000000004007a9 <+60>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x00000000004007ad <+64>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007b0 <+67>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007b3 <+70>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x00000000004007b7 <+74>:    mov    rdi,rdx
   0x00000000004007ba <+77>:    call   rax
   0x00000000004007bc <+79>:    mov    esi,eax
   0x00000000004007be <+81>:    mov    edi,0x400984
   0x00000000004007c3 <+86>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004007c8 <+91>:    call   0x400640 <printf@plt>

40    printf("%d\n",t2->gB());
   0x00000000004007cd <+96>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x00000000004007d1 <+100>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007d4 <+103>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007d7 <+106>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x00000000004007db <+110>:   mov    rdi,rdx
   0x00000000004007de <+113>:   call   rax
   0x00000000004007e0 <+115>:   mov    esi,eax
   0x00000000004007e2 <+117>:   mov    edi,0x400984
   0x00000000004007e7 <+122>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004007ec <+127>:   call   0x400640 <printf@plt>

41    return 0;
   0x00000000004007f1 <+132>:   mov    eax,0x0

42  }
   0x00000000004007f6 <+137>:   add    rsp,0x18
   0x00000000004007fa <+141>:   pop    rbx
   0x00000000004007fb <+142>:   pop    rbp
   0x00000000004007fc <+143>:   ret
```

Now that you've had suitable time to recover from the deadly diamond in the first code block, the actual question.

When `t3->gB()` is called I see the following disas (`t3` is type `TriTest`, `gB()` is virtual method `EvilTest::gB()` ):

```
   0x00000000004007a9 <+60>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x00000000004007ad <+64>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007b0 <+67>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007b3 <+70>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x00000000004007b7 <+74>:    mov    rdi,rdx
   0x00000000004007ba <+77>:    call   rax
```

The first mov moves the vtable into rax, the next dereferences it (Now we're in the vtable)

The one after that dereferences *that* to get a pointer to the function and at the bottom of that paste it's `call`ed.

So far so good, but this brings a few questions.

**Where's `this`?**
I presume `this` is loaded into `rdi` via the `mov`s at +70 and +74, but that's the same pointer as the vtable which means it's a pointer to a `TriTest` class which shouldn't have the `SubTest`s b member at all. Does the linux thiscall convention handle virtual casting inside the called method as opposed to outside?

[This was answered by rodrigo here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529939/506962)

**How do I disassemble the virtual method?**
If I knew this I could answer the previous question myself. `disas EvilTest::gB` gives me:

```
Cannot reference virtual member function "gB"
```

setting a breakpoint before the `call`, running `info reg rax` and `disas`sing that gives me:

```
(gdb) info reg rax
rax            0x4008a1 4196513
(gdb) disas 0x4008a14196513
No function contains specified address.
(gdb) disas *0x4008a14196513
Cannot access memory at address 0x4008a14196513
```

**Why are the vtables (apparently) only 8 bytes away from eachother?**
The `fdump` says there are 16 bytes between the first and second `&vtable` (Which fits the 64bit pointer and 2 ints) but the dissasembly from the second `gB()` call is:

```
   0x00000000004007cd <+96>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x00000000004007d1 <+100>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007d4 <+103>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004007d7 <+106>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x00000000004007db <+110>:   mov    rdi,rdx
   0x00000000004007de <+113>:   call   rax
```

`[rbp-0x18]` is only 8 bytes away from the previous call (`[rbp-0x20]`). What's going on?

[Answered by 500 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529649/dissassembling-multiple-virtual-inheritance-how-is-the-vtable-working/23529802?noredirect=1#comments-23529649)

I forgot the objects were heap allocated, only their pointers are on the stack

Comment: `[rbp-0x18] is only 8 bytes away from the previous call` what did you expect - there are two local pointers in scope `main()`, `t2` and `t3`. These are the actual object pointers (`this`) - not their VMTs.

Comment: You're asking a question about compiler implementation details, and didn't say what compiler?  Showing assembly, and didn't say what architecture?  Please, ask a question that doesn't demand mind-reading skills.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Of course! I'm new to C++ and keep forgetting `new` sticks stuff on the heap, thought it was stack allocated. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm no expert in the GCC internal, but I'll try to explain what I think is going on. Also note that you are not using virtual inheritance, but plain multiple inheritance, so your `EvilTest` object actually contains two `BaseTest` subobjects. You can see that is the case by trying to use `this->a` in `EvilTest`: you'll get an ambiguous reference error.

First of all be aware that every VTable has 2 values in the negative offsets:

- `-2`: the `this` offset (more on this later).
- `-1`: pointer to run-time type information for this class.

Then, from `0` on, there will be the pointers to virtual functions:

With that in mind, I'll write the VTable of the classes, with easy to read names:

#### VTable for BaseTest:

```
[-2]: 0
[-1]: typeof(BaseTest)
[ 0]: BaseTest::gB
```

#### VTable for SubTest:

```
[-2]: 0
[-1]: typeof(SubTest)
[ 0]: BaseTest::gB
```

#### VTable for TriTest

```
[-2]: 0
[-1]: typeof(TriTest)
[ 0]: BaseTest::gB
```

Up until this point nothing too interesting.

#### VTable for EvilTest

```
[-2]: 0
[-1]: typeof(EvilTest)
[ 0]: EvilTest::gB
[ 1]: -16
[ 2]: typeof(EvilTest)
[ 3]: EvilTest::thunk_gB
```

Now that is interesting! It is easier to see it working:

```
EvilTest * t2 = new EvilTest;
t2->gB();
```

This code calls the function at `VTable[0]`, that is simply `EvilTest::gB` and all goes fine.

But then you do:

```
TriTest * t3 = t2;
```

Since `TriTest` is not the first base class of `EvilTest`, the actual binary value of `t3` is different from that of `t2`. That is, the cast *advances* the pointer N bytes. The exact amount is known by the compiler at compile time, because it depends only on the static types of the expressions. In your code it is 16 bytes. Note that if the pointer is `NULL`, then it must not be advanced, thus the branch in the disassembler.

At this point is interesting to see the memory layout of the `EvilTest` object:

```
[ 0]: pointer to VTable of EvilTest-as-BaseTest
[ 1]: BaseTest::a
[ 2]: SubTest::b
[ 3]: pointer to VTable of EvilTest-as-TriTest
[ 4]: BaseTest::a
[ 5]: TriTest::c
```

As you can see, when you cast a `EvilTest*` to a `TriTest*` you have to advance `this` to the element `[3]`, that is 8+4+4 = 16 bytes in a 64-bit system.

```
t3->gB();
```

Now you use that pointer to call the `gB()`. That is done using the element `[0]` of the VTable, as before. But since that function is actually from `EvilTest`, the `this` pointer must be moved back 16 bytes before `EvilTest::gB()` can be called. That is the work of `EvilTest::thunk_gB()`, this is a little function that reads the `VTable[-1]` value and substract that value to `this`. Now everything matches!

It is worth noting that the full VTable of `EvilTest` is the concatenation of the VTable of EvilTest-as-BaseTest plus the VTable of EvilTest-as-TriTest.

Comment: Great answer! So `thunk_gB()` is essentially an intermediate function that moves `this` and then calls the original `gB`? I saw in the `-fdump*` that the this offset was actually `[-2]` and `[-1]` appeared to be a pointer to the start of the vtable. Is there any way to dereference a virtual method or even it's thunk?

Comment: @JV: Yes. The problem is that `EvilTest::gb()` expects a `this` pointer to the beginning of object, but `t3` points to the middle of it. And the compiler cannot move `t3` before calling the virtual function, because the object could be a plain `TriBase` that doesn't require moving. The `thunk_gB()` solves everything.

Comment: @JV: Also note that in both cases `t2->gB()` and `t3->gB()` the code that does the call is identical, as they are both calling `BaseTest::gB()` and it knows absolutely nothing about multiple inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, I get how it works, I was just curious where the this pointer arithmetic happened cause I saw it in the `-fdump*` but didn't see any in the disassembly and couldn't dissasemble the virtual method or the thunk

Comment: @JV: You can see the full disassembly with `g++ -save-temps`. I recommend you filter the output with `c++filt` to demangle the it.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: the object doesn't contain a vtable, it contains a *pointer* to a vtable. The first `mov` you speak of isn't loading the vtable, it's loading `this`. The second `mov` loads the pointer to the vtable which appears to be at offset `0` in the object.

Second thing: with multiple inheritance you will get multiple vtables, because each cast from one type to another requires `this` to have a binary layout compatible with the casted type. In this case you're casting `EvilTest*` to `TriTest*`. That's what the `add rax,0x10` is doing.

Comment: I understand the object contains a pointer to a vtable, and I understand the `add` on pointer assignment, my questions are more around how virtual methods are dereferenced. Where is `this` cast back to `EvilTest *` on a virtual function call from `TriTest`? How do you disassemble virtual methods? And why does it look like the 2 virtual tables are only 8 bytes apart when they should be 16?

Answer (score 0):

> **How do I disassemble the virtual method?**   If I knew this I could answer the previous question myself. `disas EvilTest::gB` gives me:
>
> ```
> Cannot reference virtual member function "gB"
> ```

I had same problem and solved it using breakpoint info to obtain method address in order to disassemble it:

```
(gdb) disassemble cSimpleChannel::deliver(cMessage*, double)
Cannot reference virtual member function "deliver"
(gdb) break cSimpleChannel::deliver
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000000000003ef50 in cSimpleChannel::deliver(cMessage*, double) at libs/sim/cchannel.cc:345
(gdb)  disassemble 0x000000000003ef50
Dump of assembler code for function cSimpleChannel::deliver(cMessage*, double):
...
...
```